# What is the hexa color of background in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, colors, hex

I'm generating a maze by removing edges from a node's neighbor. By removal, I meant to draw the removing edge as the original color of the panel. I currently have to set it to `Color.white` but it looks odd. So does anyone know the hexa code of background color in Java Swing?

[image]

Comment: *"I currently have to set it to Color.white but it looks odd."*  I would paint a solid color to the BG that was chosen by me (or the user, if I'm looking to offer 'options on game rendering').  It is a far safer strategy overall, especially when the user has their system set up to use a custom PLAF by default.  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original background colour is RGB(238,238,238) or Hex EEEEEE

**Edit**: As @GuillaumePolet pointed out, this may not be the case for all platforms - so the safest way to get it is when you first create your `JPanel` using code such as the following:

```
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();

    Color bg = jp.getBackground();

    int r = bg.getRed();
    int g = bg.getGreen();
    int b = bg.getBlue();

    System.out.println(r);
    System.out.println(g);
    System.out.println(b);
```

This is how I got 238,238,238 and I'm using Windows on Java 1.7

Comment: Thanks a lot. How could you find out though?

Comment: Use any color picker software to do that. This works in this case but other platforms may have other default background color.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet: Did you really use hexa color picker to check it manually? How is this possible?

Comment: @Chan no I did  not but it exists (ColorPix for example). Usually I simply hit print screen and paste the screenshot in gimp or paint

Comment: @Deco that solution is not good either because the background color is likely to be null. The "good" solution would be to not draw lines where it does not need to be. An alternate solution would be to pickup the colors in the UIDefaults

Comment: @GuillaumePolet unless the user has overridden the properties in the UIDefaults and set them to null, the background colour shouldn't be null when you create new Swing components.

Answer (score 7):

To avoid pointless JPanel creation (just to retrieve background color from it) use the UI constant that holds the default panel background color:

```
Color bg = UIManager.getColor ( "Panel.background" );
```

This will return different colors with different UIs set.

Using various constants you can also retrieve lots of other default values that way (not just colors).